# Cannot bind argument to parameter "FilePath" because it is null

Tags: powershell

Every time I run the script below I get

> Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FilePath' because it is null.

It was working last night. No changes have been made and this morning it just fails. the funny thing is if i save the script and then run it, it works. However if I clear console then run it again it fails.

Am I missing something obvious?

```psh
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path C:\NonStandard_Services
set-location C:\NonStandard_Services 
$Computers= Get-Content C:\computers.txt
$Report= $file
$file= $Computer
ForEach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Computer -class Win32_Service -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.StartName -ne "LocalSystem"}|
Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.StartName -ne "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService"} | 
Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.StartName -ne "NT AUTHORITY\LocalService"} |
Select-Object -Property StartName,Name,DisplayName|
    ConvertTo-Html -Property StartName,Name,DisplayName -head $HTML -body "<H2>Non-    Standard Service Accounts on $Computer</H2>"| Out-File $Report -Append}
    #Rename-Item c:\GP_Services\Report.htm $file 
    Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.extension -ne ".htm"} | Rename-Item -newname { $_.name + '.htm' }
```

Comment: Error is Out-File : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FilePath' because it is null.
At C:\Users\adminrrahul\Desktop\Svc_Accs Final03.ps1:14 char:135
+ ... H2>"| Out-File $Report -Append}
+                    ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Out-File], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand

Answer (score 4):

> ```psh
> $Report= $file
> $file= $Computer
> ForEach ($Computer in $Computers)
> {
>   ...
> }
> ```

You assign variables to other variables before they were assigned a value themselves. Change the above to this:

```psh
ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {
  $file   = $Computer
  $Report = $file
  ...
}
```

Or directly use `$Computer` in `Out-File`:

```psh
... | Out-File "$Computer.txt" -Append
```